# Find the most similar row to user input from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, similarity, euclidean-distance

I want to find the most similar row  to user input from my dataset.

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

And This is the user input :

[image]

I used scipy and sklearn with a lot of distance metrics (euclidean, hamming, cityblock, correlation, cosine...) but I didn't find good results.

My daset shape is (400,70), for the 70 features i have 25 binary features and 45 continious features.

This my Python code :

```
raw_data['distance']= distance.cdist(raw_data,
                                     raw_user.values.reshape(1, -1) , 
                                     metric='euclidean')

#Sort the rows of dataframe by column 'Distance'
raw_data = raw_data.sort_values(by ='distance')
print(raw_data.distance)
```

The result looks like this:

```
155    3.047796e+09
177    3.047797e+09
162    3.047797e+09
23     3.047797e+09
192    3.047797e+09
       ...     
72     3.047931e+09
104    3.047931e+09
Name: distance, Length: 203, dtype: float64
```

If you have other approaches or techniques to solve this problem, do not hesitate to offer me your advice. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Here you should not use **direct euclidean distance** as you have **features with variable amounts of variation** across the raw_data i.e binary features vary a by at most 1 unit while continuous features vary by several units. Hence, I am proposing a normalized euclidean distance to measure the similarity between records.
You should try this

```
# storing the standard deviation
columnWiseStandardDeviation = raw_data.std()

# calculating normalised(delta is Devided With Standard Deviation of the Column) euclidean distance
# .values have been used to access values in form of numpy array which can handle differently shaped operands
# while doing binary opration : '-' here
# deltas between corresponding column of raw_data and raw_user values are divided by their 
# column-wise standard deviations 
# to normalize them.
# then normalized DELTAS are squared and summed up and then square root of the sum is normalized euclidean distance(not a standard term), I coined it in this context

distance = ((((raw_data.values - raw_user.values)/columnWiseStandardDeviation.values)**2).sum(axis=1))**0.5

# getting the record closest to the user input record 
# df.iloc has to be user here as distance does not have indexes of original 
# dataframe as we have use value(np array) of dfs
closestRecord = raw_data.iloc[list(distance==distance.min()).index(True)]
print(closestRecord)
```

Since, I didn't have the actual data, I had generated a dataframe with random numbers to test the script

```
import random
rows, cols = 50, 10
_m = [5*random.randint(1, cols) for c in range(cols)]
print(_m)

df=pd.DataFrame(data={i:[random.randint(0, _m[i]) for j in range(rows)] for i in range(cols)})
print(df)

columnWiseStandardDeviation = df.std()
print(columnWiseStandardDeviation.values)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[random.randint(0, _m[i]) for i in range(cols)]])
distance = ((((df.values - df1.values)/columnWiseStandardDeviation.values)**2).sum(axis=1))**0.5
print(df1)

print(sorted(list(enumerate(distance)), key=lambda d:d[1]))
print('Closest Record: ', df.iloc[list(distance==distance.min()).index(True)].values)
```

Comment: Thank you for you proposition.  I applied the code that you offered me but it didn't change anything. all the distance are equal, indeed, the distance variable gave me an array of 203 similar values
   [1.31532252e + 08 1.31532252e + 08 1.31532252e + 08
   1.31532252e + 08 1.31532252e + 08 1.31532252e + 08
   .....................
  1.31532252e + 08 1.31532252e + 08 1.31532252e + 08]
After checking the variable "closestRecord" does not correspond to the most similar row of user input

Comment: Your **raw_data** has 400 rows than How can the distance have 203 values, What is the  class of your user_input variable, is it  **a Series Object or a DataFrame Object** Please mention that in the question because the shape of the np array changes everythong, here, My solution might not give the closest records but it cannot give equal values for all the distances, I have take user_input as **DataFrame** as you have shown it  as a table in image.

Comment: it's a mistake the shape is 400 and not 203.  the user input is a Series object and i reshape it  to  "raw_user.values.reshape(1, -1) " before measuring the distance.